# trying to add agency bootstrap template to Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5.4

I am trying to add the agency Bootstrap theme to a laravel 5.4 project.  The urle for the them is [Agency Bootstrap Theme](https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/agency/)

Now the first problem I am having is having the Navbar overlay the picture. Like this.[image]

What I am getting is this [image]

This is the code I have for the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <meta name="description" content="">
     <meta name="author" content="">
       <title>Agency - Start Bootstrap Theme</title>
       <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
       <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <!-- Custom CSS -->
      <link href="css/agency.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <!-- Custom Fonts -->
      <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
      <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,100,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
      <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
       <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body id="page-top" class="index">



    <!-- Navigation -->

<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse" id="mainNav">
    <div class="container">
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            Menu <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#page-top">Start Bootstrap</a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#services">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#team">Team</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

    <!-- Header -->

<header class="masthead">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="intro-text">
            <div class="intro-lead-in">Welcome To Our Studio!</div>
            <div class="intro-heading">It's Nice To Meet You</div>
            <a href="#services" class="btn btn-xl">Tell Me More</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>




    <!-- jQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-  easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/classie.js"></script>
<script src="js/cbpAnimatedHeader.js"></script>

<!-- Contact Form JavaScript -->
<script src="js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
<script src="js/contact_me.js"></script>

<!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
<script src="js/agency.js"></script>

</body>
```

I don't know why the image is below the navbar.  Any help would be appreciated.  As you can see in my example the navbar is on the left and in the template it is neatly on the right.

Answer (score 0):

On your nav element, you have a class called "fixed-top" and should be "navbar-fixed-top". You have to follow this structure:

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> Menu <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">Start Bootstrap</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="hidden">
                    <a href="#page-top"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#team">Team</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Did you verify that CSS files are loaded correctly? Also try removing masthead class on your header section.

Answer (score 0):

[image: do like this]

If you are using the template in your welcome.blade.php, for example, you need to link your css and js, and those files have to be in your public folder.

substitute:

```
<link href="css/agency.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

to:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/agency.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

do the same with js files.